# How to deploy azure functions app from azure devops correctly

Tags: java, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

Deploying a java functions app from the console works fine with the command:
`./mvnw azure-functions:deploy`

But while trying to deploy from Azure devops, the functions wont work.
The functions appear on the Functions portal.

The status for every function is "Enabled"
The settings are the same as before.
So everything seems in order, but when I try to evoke a functions. the response is 500 internal server error.

the yaml to buld the artifact:
YAML

```
Copy
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'JavaToolInstaller Java version 17 '
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'
- task: Maven@3
  displayName: 'Maven Build and Package'
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    goals: 'clean package'
    options: '-DskipTests' # Optional, to skip tests

- task: Maven@3
  displayName: 'Azure Functions Package'
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    goals: 'azure-functions:package'
    options: '' 

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
    Contents: '**/azure-functions/**'     
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/target/azure-functions/f-app-v2'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/target/azure-functions/f-app-v2'
    includeRootFolder: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

I tried to deploy an artifact from Azure devops to Azure functions,
It seems like everything is working, but invoking a functions returns 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, you are running the `./mvnw azure-functions:deploy` in Azure DevOps Pipeline Maven task.

According to [this doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#a-build-lifecycle-is-made-up-of-phases):

> The Lifecycle contains validate,compile,test, package,verify ,install, deploy.

You need to put the command: **azure-functions:deploy** in the **options** field of the Maven task.

For example:

```
- task: Maven@3
  displayName: 'Maven pom.xml'
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    options: 'azure-functions:package'
```

Then you can use the [AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-rm-web-app-deployment-v4?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) to deploy the package to Azure Function.

For example:

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: kevin1014'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: xx
    appType: functionApp
    WebAppName: xx
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_123-Maven-CI/drop/1.zip'
    enableCustomDeployment: true
    DeploymentType: runFromZip
```

Comment: putting 'azure-functions:package' in the options fix the issue.
Then I deploy using the Azure Functions Deploy task, in the release pipeline,
Which takes care of the deployment if you have the Azure Resource Manager connection.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a deployment task for azure function apps: [Azure Function Deployment: ARM](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureFunctionAppV2/README.md)

You have to create a service connection [Connect to Microsoft Azure with an ARM service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops). Then use it to deploy through Azure DevOps pipeline:

```
steps:
- task: AzureFunctionApp@2
  displayName: 'Azure Function App Deploy: $(YOUR_FUNCTION_APP)'
  inputs:
    connectedServiceNameARM: 'Your_Azure_Env_Deployment'
    appType: functionApp
    appName: '$(YOUR_FUNCTION_APP)'
    package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_YOUR_BUILD/drop/your_function_app_folder'
```

Comment: Yes, this is created automatically while selecting the Azure Functions Deploy task.